# Why can't I play the game corner in Pokemon HeartGold

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver

I want to play the game corner in my version of heart gold but when I talk to the guy to play my game crashes. I tried on multiple different ds's and it still crashed. It doesn't work in Kanto either. Can I have some help?

Comment: Where did you get your game cartridge? From a quick Google search, this seems to be a common problem in bootleg copies.

Comment: I got it off of EBay but the rest of the game works as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's likely you have a counterfeit cartridge, as that's a common problem for games bought on eBay. [This Reddit post](https://us.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/1quirl/spotting_fake_ds_pokemon_games_things_i_wish_i/) has some tips for identifying if it's legitimate or not.

Counterfeit cartridges may seem to play the same as a legitimate copy since they use the real game's code, but because of the different/inferior hardware they often have glitches that a real copy won't ([this person](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/1c47zw/pokemon_heartgold_game_corner_glitch/) for instance had the same experience as you, where the Game Corner didn't work but everything else was fine).

Even in the unlikely case that it's a defective legitimate cartridge, I doubt there would be anything you could do about it since the game is no longer being made. The best you could hope for would probably be to get a refund or exchange from the seller.

Comment: Thanks. But can it trade with an actual copy?

Comment: Also I don't mind that it's fake since it is still fun. I even found a shiny in it.

Comment: From what I've read, seems like it's hit-or-miss whether they're able to trade so you probably won't know until you try.